# Symfony and Doctrine: differences between proxy method and repository

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have an **N-to-N relationship** between two entities, let's call them A and B. I've put in the middle of them a pseudo-entity (let's call it X) that has a 1-to-N relationship with both. X does the N-to-N adding some additional info (start & end date, for example).

Now, I would like to get B elements related to a single A element, without getting the middle result, the elements of X. I stumbled upon 2 different approaches, proxies methods vs repository. What are the real differences? Which is the most elegant? What about performances?

Comment: Why the need to pseudo entity in between? Does it contain some additonal data?

Comment: Yes, I need start & end date, as stated in the question.